# How to convert INT into DWORD return code from GetExitCodeProcess [C#]

Tags: c#

I am usisng GetExitCodeProcess(processInfo.hProcess, out returnCode) as a p/invoke in C# to get the turn code of a process I started using CreateProcess - everything works fine ...

This is the code:

```
UInt32 returnCode = 0xFFFFFFFF;     // default
GetExitCodeProcess(processInfo.hProcess, out returnCode);
```

The issue is the return code itself ... the application I am launching returns codes in DWORD, for example it returns 0XB2100000 but returnCode has 2987393024 (which is the correct INT conversion).

Now,  I would like to show (log to my trace file) the value in DWORD (that is what we are used to) - anyway I can do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log the `returnCode` like this:

```
String.Format("0x{0:X8}", returnCode)
```

or

```
returnCode.ToString("X8").Insert(0, "0x")
```

This issue is also covered here:

[c# convert int to hex and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-convert-int-to-hex-and-back-again)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it just has to be converted to a hexadecimal form, like this:

```
    returnCode.ToString("X8");
```

or like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The error code was {0:X8}.", returnCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

A DWORD in C# would be a uint (UInt32).

Answer (score 0):

A DWORD and an INT are the same thing*. What you are wondering about has to do with whether a number is represented in base-10 or base-16. However, they are still the same numbers. 32 === 0x20, they are identical, not even automatically converted to eachother. Usually when you care about the base, what you are really looking for is bitwise operations (look up the operators &, | and ~).

*yes, I know DWORDs are unsigned and INTs are signed.