# How to convert Hexadecimal Color to RGB color (24 Bit)

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors, hex, system.drawing

I use C# and asp.net 4.

How to convert and **Hexadecimal Color in an equivalent RGB Color**?

```
Example: FF0000 to 255,0,0.
```

My aim is to pass this color to the method FromArgb namespace System.Drawing

```
FromArgb Method (Int32, Int32, Int32) (Alpha is implicit as opaque)
```

At the moment I use this code to Clear and Image and apply a opaque flat color:

```
System.Drawing.Graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Red));
```

This works fine with predefined color like "Red", "Black" and so on, but not obviously with a Custom more precise color.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Resource:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just do this?

```
System.Drawing.Color myColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0xFF0000);
```

Comment: How to pass it to the Clear() Method?

Comment: @GibboK: System.Drawing.Graphics.Clear(myColor);

Comment: Hi I try but does not work. I mean no error and the color it is there but maybe the Clear() method is not my option. What I can use instead?

Comment: In this format it is working: System.Drawing.Graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Red)); if I pass instead the color as you suggest so System.Drawing.Graphics.Clear(myColor) does NOT work. Any Ideas?

Comment: @GibboK: What do you mean by 'does not work'? Are you getting an exception or do you not see the color?

Comment: No exceptions just I do not see the color. I also try to debug it and I can see the color in Clear(myColor) but just does not work. What could be? Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: @GibboK: What type of graphics object do you call clear on? Do you do so inside a Paint EventHandler?

Comment: I do not use Paint EventHandler. I use Object Image System.Drawing.Bitmap. My code is wrapped in a Class in ASP.NETWebForm.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help: [C# convert integer to hex and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again)