# Help with bitwise operations

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I want to doublecheck some of my logic against a 3rd party function that I am using and I'm not sure if I've got the bitwise logic figured out correctly or not. Can someone give me a range of values for the variable 'intValue' in each scenario that will cause each conditional to return true? thanks!

```
        if ((intValue < 0 && ((intValue & 0xFFFFFF80) == 0xFFFFFF80)) ||
            (intValue & 0x0000007F) == intValue) {

        }
        else if ((intValue < 0 && ((intValue & 0xFFFF8000) == 0xFFFF8000)) ||
            (intValue & 0x00007FFF) == intValue) {

        }
        else if ((intValue < 0 && ((intValue & 0xFF800000) == 0xFF800000)) ||
            (intValue & 0x007FFFFF) == intValue) {

        }
        else {

        }
```

Comment: How about you tell us what *you* think they are, and we'll go from there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (intValue == (SByte)intValue) {
     // matches -128...127, i.e. values that fit in one byte
}
else if (intValue == (Int16)intValue) {
     // matches -32768..32767, values that fit in two bytes
}
else if (intValue == ((intValue << 8) >> 8)) {
     // matches -2**23..(2**23-1), values that fit in three bytes
}
else {
     // matches -2**31..(2**31-1), values that need four bytes
}
```

Please note that all the `intValue < 0` tests are completely redundant if the variable type is signed.

Comment: I think you mean "if the variable type is _un_ signed"?

Comment: @Lii: No, I didn't.  The subsequent test looks at the sign bit.

Comment: And I guess if the variable is unsigned the tests are equally redundant since it can't hold negative values?

Comment: @Lii: Also correct.  But redundant in a different way (implied by the data type, not the other clause in the test).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a hint:

```
int intValue = int.Parse("FFFFFF80", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

See:

[C# convert integer to hex and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again)