# Conversion of long Hex string to Integer not working as expected (works in SQL)

Tags: c#, hex, type-conversion

I have the need to convert a hex string into an integer using C#.  I've tried all of the suggestions on SO including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again) and many others.  All of them throw the same or roughly the same... error.  `Value was either too large or too small for an Int32` (same for `Int64`).

I can get the desired result in SQL Server 2008 with the following code:

```
select convert(int, 0x1B1D3E1B22176145272C1631282D221D30)
```

However THIS C# code

```
Int64.Parse("1B1D3E1B22176145272C1631282D221D30", NumberStyles.HexNumber)
Int32.Parse("1B1D3E1B22176145272C1631282D221D30", NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

...yields the errors described above.  Thoughts??  Solutions?

**UPDATE:**  The SQL Code above yields the following integer..  555949360.  With every record I can find, the sql conversion yields a unique Integer.  So the new question (I guess) is.. how to replicate the results of the SQL Convert function on this hex data?

Comment: Lets see, each digit in hex reprsents 4 bits. There are 34 digits * 4 bits = 136 bits. Not is not going to fit into a 32bit ot 64bit integer.

Comment: by my count, that's a 134 bit number. How is that supposed to fit into a 64 bit integer? You need to use a class/struct made for handling very large integers.

Comment: OK.  Bottom line is that I want to REPLICATE what SQL is doing with that #.. because it is yielding what looks and acts very much like a unique integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While SQL Server does not error, its not giving you the correct answer. Its truncating the hex string to just the lower 32bits

```
select convert(int, 0x2D221D30) = 757210416
select convert(int, 0x1B1D3E1B22176145272C1631282D221D30) = 757210416
```

If you change this to bigint you get different results:

```
select convert(bigint, 0x2D221D30) = 757210416
select convert(bigint, 0x1B1D3E1B22176145272C1631282D221D30) = 3176780635782126896
```

Comment: So I'm actually not guaranteed uniqueness with the INT conversion, correct?

Comment: Correct. At best you could use it as a hash value. If you need a unique value you should look at using the the uniqueidentifer SqlServer type.

Comment: Problem is less needing unique key.  I have that.  I have to match up to an existing Database that is now using this MD5 hash as their external key

Comment: Have you tried just storing it in a varbinary(17) field? You should be able to take your hex value constant and directly store it in that type.

Answer (score 1):

Your number is too big. It's about 9.2264939914744E+39 when `Int64.MaxValue` is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Try to use [`BigInteger.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268285.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on wolfram that is a 133bit number. You can try using a BigInteger(Byte[]) in c#

This is the binary number in case you wanted to see it:
1101100011101001111100001101100100010000101110110000101000101001001110010110000010110001100010010100000101101001000100001110100110000

Answer (score 0):

You (nor SQL Server) can decode 34 bytes into a 4 byte integer.  Hexedecimal strings represent each byte of data as two characters, one for the high nibble (4 bits), one for the low nibble.

You can use a [HexEncoding](http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/source/browse/src/Library/Formatting/HexEncoding.cs) class I wrote to decode this into bytes or write your own.

see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexidecimal