# Python Hash MD5 not equal to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, hash, md5

I'm trying to generate the same MD5 codes from Python 3 and SQL but I get always a different result.

With this Unique Identifier `f033b004-eb80-412d-9773-f4f06bb994c1`

```
SELECT  HASHBYTES('MD5', 'f033b004-eb80-412d-9773-f4f06bb994c1')
```

Result: `0x9BCE8D23CAC76AF4F61C04673CDD0081`

And then I do that calculation

```
SELECT  ABS(HASHBYTES('MD5', 'f033b004-eb80-412d-9773-f4f06bb994c1')  % 10)
```

Result: `5`

Now with python I use the `hashlib` library

```
import hashlib

m = hashlib.md5('f033b004-eb80-412d-9773-f4f06bb994c1'.encode() )
m.digest(), m.hexdigest()
```

Result: `b'\x9b\xce\x8d#\xca\xc7j\xf4\xf6\x1c\x04g<\xdd\x00\x81', 
       '9bce8d23cac76af4f61c04673cdd0081'`

And then I do the same calculations

```
    int.from_bytes( b'\x9b\xce\x8d#\xca\xc7j\xf4\xf6\x1c\x04g<\xdd\x00\x81',
                    byteorder='big', 
                    signed=False )%10
```

Result: `9`

Does anyone knows how can I get from the Python code the same results as the SQL Server ?

Comment: have you tried changing the byteorder?

Comment: Yes I did that, sorry for didn't write the answer but it is not like SQL Selver. It returns me 1.

Comment: On the Python side, you are converting `bytes` to an `int`, and taking the modulus of the `int`.  On the SQL Server, you are taking the modulus of the output of `HASHBYTES` - a `VARBINARY`.  Are you sure that the modulus of a `VARBINARY` is the same as that of the value cast to an integer?

Comment: No I am not sure. But do you know how can I check it or do it correctly in Python 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because SQL server returns the MD5 hash in UPPERCASE and Python in lowercase. The UPPER and lower case bytes have, of course, different byte values.

Comment: I already test that, but I get the same result even if MD5 is lowercase or uppercase. If you get the same result as SQL Server with uppercase please post me the 3-4 lines of your Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this... the problem is that when SQL server converts the hash into integer to perform the modulo, it will not give you the correct integer because the hexadecimal is too big (check out the top answer in here: [Conversion of long Hex string to Integer not working as expected (works in SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493890/conversion-of-long-hex-string-to-integer-not-working-as-expected-works-in-sql))

On the other hand, python can do the conversion correctly because the max integer size is as much as memory allows

Answer (score 0):

This is true for BigQuery, not sure it it applies to SQL Server too, but the reason for this discrepancy is that the BigQuery functions for MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, and SHA-512 return base64-encoded representations of the hash values, while the Python hashlib library returns hexadecimal representations.

This code will return the same value as SQL:

```py
    hash_obj = hashlib.md5()
    hash_obj.update(input_string.encode())
    hash_bytes = hash_obj.digest()
    base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(hash_bytes).decode()
```