# change numeric base of negative numbers

Tags: c#, numbers, converters, numeric

How to convert a negative decimal number to a hexadecimal one?
I know how to convert positive numbers from one base to another.
The widows calculator returns a huge number something like FFFFFFFFFFFFCFC7 in hex for -12345 in dec.The value that I need to process further more is CFC7, but I don't know how to get it using C#.

Comment: Look at this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure if that is what you need:

```
int i = -12345;
string test = i.ToString("X"); // test will hold: "FFFFCFC7"
int HexI = Convert.ToInt32(test, 16); // HexI will hold: -12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int decimalValue = -12345;
string hexVal = String.Format("{0:x2}", decimalValue);
```