# Making a operation with "if" for hex and dec format

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# convert integer to hex and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again)

I want to make a code with "if" to make me that:
We are starting the program and we have one textbox - "textbox1" and one button - "button1". We need to start a cycle that starts to count from 0 and each click on the button1 brings it +1, so for now we have:
Start program>click button>cycle starts and we have 1> click again - we have 2 and etc.
(this 1,2,3 ...n wont be shown anywhere)
After that we need to show the current value of the cycle in this HEX format - "00-00-00-00" in textbox1. So we got:
First click will be first moment of cycle, so we have current DEC value "1" and in hex it must be - "00-00-00-01" and here it comes the hottest part(for me ..) when the DEC value=255 in HEX it must be - "00-00-00-FF" and when the cycle(dec value) hits 256 it must be "00-00-01-00" and again the same till the dec value=511 - we will have "00-00-01-FF" and on decvalue=512 we will have "-00-00-02-00".

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: maybe you should add a paragraph or two to your question

Comment: Seems to be already solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again

Comment: How do you count and display the values? What did you try?

Comment: To be fair, I find carry-over addition to be the hottest as well. Just don't tell my wife.

Comment: The entire thing just comes down to converting an int to a hex string. That question has been answered many times.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want:

```
public int Counter { get; set; }

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    Counter++;
    textbox1.Text = Counter.ToString("X");
}
```

But there is no "if" in it... :(

Comment: What i need to put on get and set ? it wants to "declare a body" ...

Comment: Normally you don't need a body, this is called an [Auto-Implemented Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).