# How do I convert this Hex to an Integer?

Tags: c#, hex

This is really confusing me. In a program for some unknown reason a counter is being stored to track the state between two databases. This is only essentially only an incremental counter.

The code stores this counter:

```
byte[] counter;
```

When it is stored in the database it gets rendered to a string like this...

```
0x00010471000001BF001F
```

I want to write an app that tells me if one is higher than the other and by how many by entering the two numbers. But I dont know how to convert these numbers into an integer representation.

Does anybody know what is going on and if this is possible?

Answer (score 4):

As the number is 20 hex digits (80 bit) it is too big to store in an int (32 bit) or a long (64 bit).  You can use the `BigInteger` on .NET 4.0 or greater. (In .NET 4.0 you have to add a reference to System.Numerics.dll)

```
var bigint = new System.Numerics.BigInteger(counter)
```

As Øyvind pointed out, the above needs the byte array in little-endian order, i.e. new byte [] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } would evaluate to 1.  Use Array.Reverse to work around this if necessary.

Since you have the number as a string, you should use `BigInteger.Parse`, note however you will have to trim the "0x" from the start

```
var bigint = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("00010471000001BF001F",
                 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber,
                 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This is the best answer imo. But one caveat here, is that the BigInteger constructor needs the byte array in a little-endian order. If your byte array is not, then you need to use `Array.Reverse(counter);` first.

Comment: thanks youve answered the question but do you also know any idea how I can use a string that the byte has been written to? A string like Ox00010471000001BF001F?

Answer (score 0):

based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again) you can use

`int intNumber = int.Parse(counter,system.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);`

Comment: int can hold a maximum of 4 bytes, not 10 as this question requires.