# Convert int to hex format 0xyy c#

Tags: c#, hex

I need to write a function which receives one parametrer of type `int` (decimal), and returns `string` containing the int value in hex, **but in format 0xyy**.
More than that I want the answer to be in a fixed format of 4 Bytes
For example:

```
int b = 358;
string ans = function(b);
```

In this case ans = "0x00 0x00 0x01 0x66"

```
int a = 3567846; 
string ans = function(a);
```

In this case ans = "0x00 0x36 0x70 0xE6"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should match your examples:

```
static string Int32ToBigEndianHexByteString(Int32 i)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
    string format = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian
        ? "0x{3:X2} 0x{2:X2} 0x{1:X2} 0x{0:X2}"
        : "0x{0:X2} 0x{1:X2} 0x{2:X2} 0x{3:X2}";
    return String.Format(format, bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
}
```

Comment: Excellent usage of Big/Little Endian! +1

Answer (score 1):

I think the format you want is on similar lines

```
int ahex = 3567846;
byte[] inthex = BitConverter.GetBytes(ahex);
Console.WriteLine("0x"+ BitConverter.ToString(inthex).Replace("-"," 0x"));
```

Comment: Neat, didn't know about that `ToString` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
int val = 1;
string conv = ("0x" + val.ToString("X4"));
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).