# Convert int to hex with leading zeros

Tags: c#, hex, string-formatting

How to convert int (4 bytes) to hex ("`XX XX XX XX`") without cycles?

for example:

```
i=13 hex="00 00 00 0D"
```

`i.ToString("X")` returns `"D"`, but I need a 4-bytes hex value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again

Comment: @Joetjah Those answers only mention `X`, which the OP already knows. This question is about having leading `0` digits.

Comment: It's fine to close this as a duplicate if you find one, but the question you currently closed it as is no duplicate. The answers over there recommend `ToString("X")`, which doesn't produce the leading zeros the OP asked for.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can specify the minimum number of digits by appending the number of hex digits you want to the `X` format string. Since two hex digits correspond to one byte, your example with 4 bytes needs 8 hex digits. i.e. use `i.ToString("X8")`.

If you want lower case letters, use `x` instead of `X`. For example `13.ToString("x8")` maps to `0000000d`.

Answer (score 16):

try this:

```
int innum = 123;
string Hex = innum .ToString("X");  // gives you hex "7B"
string Hex = innum .ToString("X8");  // gives you hex 8 digit "0000007B"
```