# A code to generate a string dynamically according to specific input

Tags: java, c#

I want to generate string dynamically according to specific input lick this
if the input = 1 , the string output = `00000`
and if it =10 , output = `0000a`
input= 16 ,output = `00010`
and so on .
the generated string is numbers from 0 to 9 and letters from a to f
and the string length is constant for all generated strings.

## and what the code if the output is not a hex , just a string like `aaaaa` for 1,

and `aaaab` for 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert int to hex with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919979/convert-int-to-hex-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: what is the logic between these values? `1` to `0000` could be minus one; `10` to `000a` just base changed; `16` to `0000f` again minus one but also base changed. Or just mistyped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you made a mistake and the output of `1` should be `00001` and the output `16` should be `00010`.

Use `String.format`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(toHex(0, 5));
    System.out.println(toHex(1, 5));
    System.out.println(toHex(10, 5));
    System.out.println(toHex(16, 5));
}

private static String toHex(int input, int length) {
    return String.format("%0" + length + "x", input);
}
```

**Output:**

```
00000
00001
0000a
00010
```

Comment: and same for 16?

Comment: little hint: `%05x` would pad with zeros, no need for replace....

Comment: yes that was my mistake , what if the output is not a hex number , what if it just a string, what is the code for that. and than you .

Comment: @BabikerBushra Do you mean "decimal notation" by "just a string"? If so you would have to write `"%0" + length + "d"` instead of `"%0" + length + "x"`. Take a look at the available [formatting options](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Best I can see in terms of c# that fits your rules is:

```
string NumToHex(int num){
  if(num == 10)
    return num.ToString("x5");
  else
    return (num-1).ToString("x5");
}
```