# Divide hex characters

Tags: c#, hex, character, divide

I need help to divide hex characters something like this. I know this does not work. If i enter 418 my answer should be 20C. Im using C# Thanks

```
private void button23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //calculator
    {

        {
            offset = textBox10.Text;

           offset hex / 2 = offset2


            textBox11.Text = offset2;

        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# convert integer to hex and back again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumberStyles` is a bit esoteric but it's how you do it:

```
int offset = int.Parse(textBox10.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
int offset2 = offset / 2;
textBox11.Text = String.Format("{0:X}", offset2);
```

Of course, you might need more processing and validation of the user input. Look at `int.TryParse` and different int sizes (e.g. `Int64`), too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int.Parse` to convert your hex string to an `int`, perform any arithmetic operation you require on it, then use `ToString` to convert it back to a hex string.

```
string offset = textBox10.Text;
int val = int.Parse(offset, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
int div = val / 2;
string offset2 = div.ToString("X");
textBox11.Text = offset2;
```

Comment: This also works great, for another part that im going to do. Thank you