# Converting a value to Hexadecimal and Decimal

Tags: c#

I have this value `10732` I converted this value to ´hexadecimal` like this:

```
string hex = string.Join(string.Empty, "10732".Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X")));
```

And I got as result: `3130373332`

But, using the Calculator of W7 in "programmer" mode.  When I convert `10732`from DECIMAL to HEX,
I got `29EC` as result. Why ? How may I do this using C#?

Comment: There's a pretty big difference between converting a string an an int to hexadecimal. The c# does it for the string, the calculator for the int. Which one do you want ?

Comment: duplication of [C# convert integer to hex and back again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again)

Comment: You are converting figure by figure. That is not how you convert int to hex

Comment: @C4stor So what I was doing was convert each CHAR of my string to hex ?  how may I get the `29EC` ?

Comment: See the answer linked by Parse.

Comment: Thanks for the -1 and the link @Parse 
worked.

Answer (score 6):

You are converting *each character* in the string to a hex.

```
Char   Int value (dec)   Hex value
1      49                31
0      48                30
7      55                37
3      51                33
2      50                32
```

You should be simply converting the int directly:

```
10732.ToString("X")
```

If the value is a string, convert to an integer first:

```
Int.Parse("10732").ToString("X")
```

Comment: +1 For the OPs clarity string -> int -> hex would simply be `(int.Parse("10732")).ToString("X");`

Comment: Oded, is there a way to do this working with doubles? Like, If I want to get the int value of R$ `107.32` ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro - cast to `int`. You will get `107`.