# See my packet details via Wireshark as byte instead of hex

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, packet

I want to build `DHCP` packet and in the build process i am get params from user for example `Agent Circuit Id` (string) - attribute number 82.
After build my packet i am send this packet and see the result via `Wireshark`
My problem is that when i see my packet i see my `Agent Circuit Id` value as hex and i want to see this value as byte for example:

```
string agentCircuitId = "33445566778899";
```

i want this field will be 2 bytes `33 44 55 66 77 88 99`

in my result i try the string "1234" and the result is `31 32 33 34`

http://s27.postimg.org/bdhe9j4hv/123.png

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Should the values of the bytes be decimal 12 and 34? Or should the byte values be hexadecimal 0x12 and 0x34 (i.e., the string being a hex number)?

Comment: the string is hex number

Comment: You might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again for converting the hex-string to a number and set that number for the "Agent Circuit ID" option. Make sure you use the `short` type (= 16-bit integer)

Comment: I didn't understand why is good for my purpose

Comment: What did you not understand?

Comment: My input is string, in order to convert it i need int/byte[]/string ?

Comment: No, look at the SO question i linked to more carefully. It is called "convert integer to hex and **back again**", that means it (and its answers) cover both conversion from *int* to *hex string*, and conversion from **hex string to int**. The latter you are interested in (in your case just use *short* instead of *int*, because you are apparently dealing with a 16-bit value)

Comment: Please see my update, this is what i need (i have changed the example) - your given link is still what i need ?

Comment: Ah, i see. You can actually have an arbitrary number of bytes, correct? (please also update the text below the example - it still mentions "12" and "34")

Comment: Alright. SO also has already a topic with plenty of answers (one surely will fit your needs): [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: I am using byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex) and it works fine if my string is "1234" and return 2 bytes but in case my string is "12345" the return byte[] is still 2 bytes so i have 1 byte missing because now i need to insert 3 values (12, 34, 5)

Comment: A byte in a sequence of hex-notation characters has always two digits. If you get an input with an odd number of digits, cut of the last digit from the string, convert the string as usual and convert the last digit separately...

Comment: No problem. On a side note: Inputting "12345" should perhaps rather be treated as "012345", and thus result in bytes 01,23,45. A byte sequence of 12,34,5 would normally correspond to the hex string "123405".