# Convert ASCII Console Input to Hex

Tags: c#, type-conversion, hex, ascii, apdu

I'm programming in c# and trying to convert a console input to Hex. 
Input is a number between 1-256 (ex. 125)
The converted number should look like this:

```
fpr 125: 0x31, 0x32, 0x35
```

I already tried to solve my problem for hours by using:

```
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Senke)
```

but it always shows me `byte[]`.

I need this conversion for creating an APDU to write Information on my smartcard by using my SmartCard Application the final Apdu will look like this:

```
{ 0xFF, 0xD6, 0x00, 0x02, 0x10, 0x31, 0x32, 0x35}
```

I hope that someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert integer to hex, use: (more information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again))

```
int devValue = 211;
string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");
```

To further elaborate, the following will produce your desired output:

```
string input = "125"; // your input, could be replaced with Console.ReadLine()

foreach (char c in input) {
    int decValue = (int)c; // Convert ASCII character to an integer
    string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X"); // Convert the integer to hex value

    Console.WriteLine(hexValue);
}
```

Code would produce the following output:

```
31
32
35
```

Comment: thank you so far, now i get the output without the 0x and i need it for this function, i need for each number a byte as a variable, for example a=0x31, b=0x32, c=0,35 to use it in this APDU byte[] WriteAPDU = { 0xFF, 0xD6, 0x00, 0x02, 0x10, 0x31, 0x32, 0x35}

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
int d = 65;  // Capital 'A'

string h= d.ToString("X");  // to hex
int d2 = int.Parse(h, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); //to ASCII
```