# Convert a String to an Integer

Tags: c#

I have an String, which looks like:

```
string a = "1AD9B1E7D11FEA4F4C89493E1";
```

and now i want to split this string after every 4th character, so that it looks like this after spliting:

```
string[] splitted = { "1AD9", "B1E7", "D11F", "EA4F", "C894", "93E1" };
```

then i want to convert each of these strings to an int, so i basicly need to convert hexadecimal to int(i think)
and then i want to do some math with these ints and then at the end convert it back to "string" or hexadecimal and then put the different strings together, so that i have a string like at the beginning. thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should show what have you tried so far. Otherwise your question belongs to the category 'give me teh codez' and should be closed

Comment: Please include that in the question by editing your post...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# convert integer to hex and back again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again)

Comment: @Steve and yet, how many will line up to give it?  Boo, putresence and filth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert to the string array:

```
string a = "1AD9B1E7D11FEA4F4C89493E1";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 0)
        sb.Append(' ');
    sb.Append(a[i]);
}
string formatted = sb.ToString();
string[] splitted = formatted.Split(' ');
```

The above just inserts a space every 4th character, then splits the string at the spaces

To convert to int:

```
foreach(string s in splitted){
    int num = Int32.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    //do what you want with num
}
```

To convert back to hex, you can use:

```
string someString = someInteger.ToString("X4");
```

The x4 just means the string will be 4 digits long

Here is a working example that just prints the converted int and converted hex values:

```
            string a = "1AD9B1E7D11FEA4F4C89493E1";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 0)
                    sb.Append(' ');
                sb.Append(a[i]);
            }
            string formatted = sb.ToString();
            string[] splitted = formatted.Split(' ');

            foreach(string s in splitted){
                int num = Int32.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                Console.WriteLine(num);
                string someString = num.ToString("X4");
                Console.WriteLine(someString);
            }
```

Comment: okay the converting from an int to hex works thanks :) but the conversion from the splitted string to int crashes :(

Comment: I've edited my answer, just realised I didn't cover spliiting the word into an array

Comment: Editted again, changed the for loop to a foreach loop, that should work now :)

Comment: okay, the for loop gives an error, it says insert ";", but i don't know where, i used to use forloops like For(int i = 0;i<3;i++) :D sry for being a noob, i just started getting into the c-language

Comment: Which for loop creates the error? Did you see my edit about  changing it to a foreach loop?

Comment: I've added a working example

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly, as far as i can see you are pretty good at the c-language, so you maybe also know how to do the following, and avoid me from posting again ^^ I have an inputstring, and i want to check if this string fits the format of a date:
it should return true if the string looks like "00.00.0000 * 00.00" and false if it doesnt looks like that, i didn't knew how to set that the 00 can be numbers from 0-9 because making a comparison to every single possible date would take ways to long.

Comment: No problem, could you possibly set my answer to correct?
Honestly I think you should post that as a separate question as it could help others with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is splitting the string. This can be accomplished easily using a `for` loop and `Skip()` and `Take()`. I went with this method because if your string length isn't a multiple of 4 `Substring()` will not catch any end characters. Also, I used a `List<string>` for the split as I don't know if the input string is a fixed length or not. If it is a fixed length, you could easily replace it with a `string[]`.

```
var splitted = new List<string>();

for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i += 4)
{
    var s = new string(a.Skip(i).Take(4).ToArray());
    splitted.Add(s);
}
```

Then you can parse your numbers into integers and do your calculations on each number and store them into a new `List<int>`

```
var numbers = new List<int>();

foreach (var item in splitted)
{
    var n = int.Parse(item, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    int result = // Do whatever you need to do to each number.

    numbers.Add(result);
}
```

After that, you can just loop through the numbers and use a `StringBuilder` to rebuild the string.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var item in numbers)
{
    sb.Append(item.ToString("X"));
}
```

Then just call

```
sb.ToString();
```

to get your resultant string.

If you need the numbers directly to do math, you can just store the numbers in the `numbers` list instead and do your calculations as you want. Then you can loop through the results of those calculations in the final `foreach` loop instead to get your rebuilt string.

Answer (score 0):

Might as well get my two sense into this question

```
            string hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            string a = "1AD9B1E7D11FEA4FC89493E1";
            int[] nibbles = a.Select(x => hex.IndexOf(x)).ToArray();
            List<UInt16> results = new List<ushort>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nibbles.Count(); i += 4)
            {
                results.Add((ushort)((nibbles[i] << 12) | (nibbles[i + 1] << 8) | (nibbles[i + 2] << 4) | nibbles[i + 3]) );
            }​
            string[] test = results.Select(x => x.ToString("X4")).ToArray();​
```