# Binary reading from string

Tags: c#

I'm writing little decoder. User enter string (hex) that program should decode.

My problem is that `int` value is not the same as inputed, therefore I don't know how should I advance after reading binary. Am I missing point on how to read binary ?

```
string input = "0802";

byte[] arr = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input);

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(arr))
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        int a = reader.ReadInt32();
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        //output: 842020912
    }
}
```

Comment: what value is not the same as input?

Comment: You're encoding a `string`, but then try to read an `int`.  They are not going to be the same.

Comment: This whole thing could just be one line of code: `int num = Convert.ToInt32("0802", 16);`

Comment: @NicoRiff Well I imagined that ```a``` would be same as ```input```.

Comment: @itsme86 I only showed one peace, there would be quite long string that should be decoded and it should be sorted.

Comment: @SoulJam Why?  What you encode are the binary values that represent the characters of your string.  That's completely different from reading an integer value from a binary stream.

Comment: Very confusing what you are trying to do. Possibly just [hex <-> int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again) - but you've obviously already seen that post and likely want something different.

Comment: @SoulJam You need to do a better job of explaining what it is you're trying to do. For example, what constitutes a number? Is it every 2 hexdigits? From the question it looks like it should be the whole input string, but then you're talking about a longer string that contains multiple numbers.

Comment: @itsme86 Indeed I wasn't very clear, sorry. My main concern was to understand ```ReadInt32()``` better. Since I was confused if my outcome was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. You read 4 bytes from the string so they are interpreted as 4 bytes of your `int`.

If you check the hex value of your "incorrect" number `842020912` it will give you `0x32303830` and reading every byte as ASCII gives `"2080"`.

The order is reversed as you are reading the value as little-endian.

Comment: I was confused what I was getting from function ```ReadInt32()```. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Now just curious if there is some simple way of getting to that ASCII without much complicated conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the hard way.  I using Bytes but can modify for 1in16, or int32 very easily. :

```
            string input = "0802";
            List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 2)
            {
                bytes.Add(byte.Parse(input.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
            }
```