# C# Multiple String Compare

Tags: c#

i have big list of string like

actually im using binary Writer

```
            case btn_click:
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(theFiles));

                for (int i = 0x000004; i <= 0x000005; i++)
                {
                    bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x000004;
                    string cmp = spn1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    if (cmp == "A") bw.Write(0x0123);
                    if (cmp == "B") bw.Write(0x0456);
                    if (cmp == "C") bw.Write(0x0789);
                }

                for (int i = 0x000008; i <= 0x000009; i++)
                {
                    bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x000008;
                    string cmp = spn2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    if (cmp == "A") bw.Write(0x0123);
                    if (cmp == "B") bw.Write(0x0456);
                    if (cmp == "C") bw.Write(0x0789);
                }
                for (int i ...
                {
                    ...
                }
...
```

how to avoid write repeat of string a, b , c ?

so by an answer by @Olexiy Dymashok i can solve the problem ^^
im put string cmp at public

```
public string cmp { get; private set; }

     for (int i = 0x000004; i <= 0x000005; i++)
                {
                    bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x000004;
                    cmp = spn1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    bw.Write(SelectDataForBinaryWriter("ListData"));
                }

     for (int i = 0x000004; i <= 0x000005; i++)
                {
                    bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x000004;
                    cmp = spn2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    bw.Write(SelectDataForBinaryWriter("ListData"));
                }

    private int SelectDataForBinaryWriter(string input)
    {
        int output = 0;
        if (cmp == "A") output = 0x0000;
        if (cmp == "B") output = 0x0123;
        if (cmp == "C") output = 0x0456;
        return output;
    }
```

thanks you

Comment: does 'do something' depend on the i variable within the for loops?

Comment: What are you trying to actually do, what's the problem are you trying to solve? Which version of C# is available to you?

Comment: Declare them outside the loops?  It's not clear what you're doing in this code.

Comment: both blocks are the same. You don't even seem to need a for loop, since you're not using the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those strings are the same for all the cases - make them global:

```
string a = "test";
string b = "try";
string c = "compare";
//case 1
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
     if (a == b) { do something };
     if (a == c) { do something};
 }
 //case 2
 for (int i = 3; i <= 4; i++)
{
     if (a == b) { do something };
     if (a == c) { do something};
}
```

Doing this you will avoid repeating initializing this strings in every case

**Edit 1**

you can create function to select values:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
     bw.Write(SelectDataForBinaryWriter("A"));
}
...
private int SelectDataForBinaryWriter(string input)
{
    int output = 0;
    switch (input) // edit your own cases here
    {
        case "A":
            output = 0x123;
            break;
        case "B":
            output = 0x456;
            break;
        case "C":
            output = 0x789;
            break;
        default:
            output = some_default_value_here;
            break;
    }

    return output;
}
```

As I can see, you are writing hex values, so you can also consider returning already parsed value - [C# convert integer to hex and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again)

Comment: yep i editd my question

Comment: @BlakRUSH answer edited, please take a look

Comment: Thks @olexiy , now i can save more line :D

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static class containing a, b and c as constant fields.

```
public static class Arbitrary
{
    public const string A = "test";
    ...
}
```