# Convert 0x0000F85D String to int C#

Tags: c#, string, int

in trying to convert this string 0x0000F85D
to integer value
i tried all the popular methods 
but did not worked 
any ideas please
`var hello= "0x0000F85D"; 
var i = ??? ;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# convert integer to hex and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again)

Comment: the int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) method only works without the leading 0x.  The docs ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx )say that Strings that are parsed using this style cannot be prefixed with "0x" or "&h"

Answer (score 2):

```
Convert.ToInt32("0x0000F85D", 16);
```

Have a read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx