# Send integer as varbinary to SQL Trigger

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, unicode, ado.net

I use this code to set context_info within a SQL-Trigger

```
string strUser = _app.Settings.User;
string strInt = "";

// strInt += '\x0100'; => becomes 1 in trigger
strInt += '\x0000';
strInt += '\x0200'; //=> becomes two in the trigger
strInt += '\u0000';
strInt += '\u0300';//=> becomes 3 in the trigger

// strInt += '\x0000'; 
// strInt += '\x0210'; //=> becomes 4098 in the trigger( 4096=1 + 2=2)
// strInt += '\x0000'; 
// strInt += '\u1300';//=> becomes 19 in the trigger


// strInt += '\x0200'; // = 131072
// strInt += '\x0000'; 
// strInt += '\u0100';// = 65536
// strInt += '\u0000';

//strInt += '\x0000'; 
//strInt += '\x0003'; //768
//strInt += '\u0000';
//strInt += '\u0002'; //512

string strUser = "myself";
string strContextValue = strInt + strUser + "$";
string strContext = "declare @context_info varbinary(120) set @context_info =  CONVERT(varbinary(120), N'" + strContextValue + "') set context_info @context_info";

 SqlCommand scContext = new SqlCommand(strContext, conn, tran);
 scContext.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In the Trigger the first 8 chars are interpreted as two numbers:

```
declare @ctxt varbinary(128)
select @ctxt=context_info from master.dbo.sysprocesses where spid = @@spid
set @session=substring(@ctxt,1,4)
set @contextid=substring(@ctxt,5,4)
```

I'm not the author of the trigger so I can't change it but it would be great if you could explain me what kind of magic is going on here?
How can be ensured that the first 8 chars are numbers? How do I have to encode two Intergers so that they become 4 chars long at the SQL-Trigger?

I already did a lot of encoding stuff but can't look thru it.

When I load the corretly written (from another application) data back to a c# DataTable I can get the correct value of the numbers by doing:

```
 byte[] binaryString = (byte[])dataTable.Rows[0][2];
 string x = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(binaryString);

 string strSubX2 = x.Substring(3, 4);
 int iResult = BitConverter.ToInt32(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strSubX2), 0);
```

Comment: Can you explain what part you don't understand?

Comment: How can be ensured that the first 8 chars are numbers?

Comment: There is no guarantee of that, this code just converts a string to binary, if you look at that it will always numeric as your looking at the numeric value of each byte.  Still not sure what your asking.

Comment: How to encode two integer in c# so that CONVERT creates 8 chars as shown in SQL Code...Pls look at: set @session=substring(@ctxt,1,4). How do I have to format my SQL-Command so that CONVERT encodes an intager in 1-4 ?

Comment: Can't you just use fill with leading zeros? Like string.Format("{0:D4}", session) + string.Format("{0:D4}", contextId)

Comment: Nope. Since it just makes a text representation of the string. So if the first Integer is 8 digits long this would use all space (8)...

Comment: But the Trigger Code you pasted above extracts for example @session from the first 4 characters of the context_info ... the the max value you can pass there should be 9999 ... 8 digits integer values cannot be handled like this ... you could increase the range a bit by encoding the values as hexadecimal string ...

Comment: Thats the point!! As described above! Also samples are included! The question is simple and also written above: How to encode? How to encode int so that SQL-CONVERT does it right?

Comment: I think you might have an XY problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your confusion comes from misunderstanding what `varbinary` is. `varbinary` is a string of bytes, not chars. It is not even really a string, it is an array of bytes.

`varbinary` can be represented as a string of hexadecimal values and `varbinary` constants in T-SQL code are represented as hexadecimal strings. Two hexadecimal characters per byte.

The [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function in T-SQL can work with strings (`varchar`) and with bytes (`varbinary`).

> Syntax
>
> SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
>
> The values for start and length must be specified in number of
>   characters for `ntext`, `char`, or `varchar` data types and **bytes** for `text`,
>   `image`, `binary`, or `varbinary` data types.

So, the following T-SQL trigger code

```sql
declare @ctxt varbinary(128)
select @ctxt=context_info from master.dbo.sysprocesses where spid = @@spid
set @session=substring(@ctxt,1,4)
```

takes first 4 bytes (**not chars**) from the `@ctxt` array of bytes and assigns them to the `@session` variable. What type is `@session`? Most likely it is `int`.

Run this sample code in SSMS and you'll see the hexadecimal representation of some integers:

```sql
DECLARE @T TABLE (I int);
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(0),
(1),
(3),
(19),
(255),
(256),
(512),
(768),
(4098),
(65535),
(65536),
(131072),
(1234567890),
(-1),
(-65535);

SELECT
    I, CONVERT(varbinary(120), I) AS BinI
FROM @T;
```

**Result**

```
+------------+------------+
|     I      |    BinI    |
+------------+------------+
|          0 | 0x00000000 |
|          1 | 0x00000001 |
|          3 | 0x00000003 |
|         19 | 0x00000013 |
|        255 | 0x000000FF |
|        256 | 0x00000100 |
|        512 | 0x00000200 |
|        768 | 0x00000300 |
|       4098 | 0x00001002 |
|      65535 | 0x0000FFFF |
|      65536 | 0x00010000 |
|     131072 | 0x00020000 |
| 1234567890 | 0x499602D2 |
|         -1 | 0xFFFFFFFF |
|     -65535 | 0xFFFF0001 |
+------------+------------+
```

Your C# code in the question doesn't make much sense. Wrapping both `strInt + strUser` into `CONVERT(varbinary(120), N'" + strContextValue + "')` doesn't make sense.

The C# code should construct the binary array. The T-SQL trigger code expects that first 4 bytes of this array is `@session`, next 4 bytes is `@contextid`. **bytes, not characters**.

So, if you want to pass, say, `131072` decimal as `@session`, `1234567890` decimal as `@contextid`, plus `myself$` string as extra info you should run the following T-SQL code:

```sql
declare @context_info varbinary(128); -- note 128 length here
set @context_info = 0x00020000;
-- note, there are no quotes around the constants, they are numbers, not strings
set @context_info = @context_info + 0x499602D2;
set @context_info = @context_info + CONVERT(varbinary(120), N'myself$');
-- note 120 length here, first 8 bytes are used by two integers
set context_info @context_info;
```

Run this code in SSMS, but replace of the last line with `SELECT @context_info;` to see what it does. You'll get the following result:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|                (No column name)                |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 0x00020000499602D26D007900730065006C0066002400 |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

You can see the binary representation of two integers plus binary representation of the unicode text string.

In C# you construct this code by concatenating hexadecimal representation of integers.
Note, that you should not enclose `0x00020000` and `0x499602D2` into quotes or `CONVERT(varbinary, ...)`. You should enclose only the `myself$` string into the `CONVERT(varbinary, ...)`.

The C# code should look something like this:

```cs
string strUser = "myself$";
int iSession = 131072;
int iContextID = 1234567890;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("declare @context_info varbinary(120);");
sb.Append("set @context_info = 0x");
sb.Append(iSession.ToString("X8"));
sb.Append(";");
sb.Append("set @context_info = @context_info + 0x");
sb.Append(iContextID.ToString("X8"));
sb.Append(";");
sb.Append("set @context_info = @context_info + CONVERT(varbinary(120), N'");
sb.Append(strUser);
sb.Append("');");
sb.Append("set context_info @context_info;");

string strContext = sb.ToSTring();

SqlCommand scContext = new SqlCommand(strContext, conn, tran);
scContext.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

See also [C# convert integer to hex and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139957/4116017)

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I really did a lot of investigation and also found the link you have posted. However, I wasn't able to make it work.