# Converting array value to hex in C#

Tags: c#, hex

How can I convert `array[1]` to *hexadecimal* in C#

```
array[1] = 1443484
```

I have tried the following but it *doesn't compile*:

```
StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(array[1].Length * 2);

foreach (byte b in array[1])
  hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

string value = hex.ToString();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert integer to hexadecimal and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/convert-integer-to-hexadecimal-and-back-again)

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: `string value = Convert.ToString(array[1], 16);` and you'll have `"16069c"`

Comment: What type is your `array` variable exactly? Your question is unclear and contradictory about it. You saying "_array[1]=1443484_" implies your `array` variable is an array of integers. But your code example, specifically `array[1].Length` and `foreach (byte b in array[1])`, implies that your `array` variable is a collection of byte arrays... So, what are we really dealing here with?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks.. I am getting error(can not convert from int to Iformat provider) for 16 using this solution

Comment: @aishwarya: Demo with `Convert.ToString(array[1], 16)` : https://dotnetfiddle.net/gE5B47

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to obtain hexadecimal representation, you can do it in one go:

```
 // 16069c
 string value = Convert.ToString(array[1], 16);
```

Or

```
 string value = array[1].ToString("x");
```

Or (padded version: at least `8` characters)

```
 // 0016069c
 string value = array[1].ToString("x8");
```

If you want to manipulate with `byte`s try `BitConverter` class

```
 byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(array[1]);

 string value = string.Concat(bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
```

Your code amended:

```
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // For Marshal

 ...

 // Marshal.SizeOf - length in bytes (we don't have int.Length in C#)
 StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(Marshal.SizeOf(array[1]) * 2);

 // BitConverter.GetBytes - byte[] representation
 foreach (byte b in BitConverter.GetBytes(array[1]))
   hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

 // You can well get "9c061600" (reversed bytes) instead of "0016069c"
 // if BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == true 
 string value = hex.ToString();
```