# How do I add to a hex number?

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement the following lines in python to C#

```
final_reg = hex(gain_st)+'400020'
```

After that, I need to write `final_reg` to a register which in python was written this way.

```
serial.write(int('A', 16), int(final_reg, 16))
```

But In C# I implemented my `serial.write` using a function called `write_word_segment_addr()`; For Ex, if I want to write `90` to `A` I write like this currently:

```
mem.write_word_segment_addr(0x7c032, 0x00000090);      //A
```

How do I convert `gain_st` which is a `UInt32` to `hex` and then add `400020` and then convert it to 0x format seen above so that I may write to my register?

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/convert-integer-to-hexadecimal-and-back-again

Comment: To hexadecimal `string`: `string s = intValue.ToString("x");` back to `int`: `int v = Convert.ToInt32(s, 16);`

Answer (score 1):

```
final_reg = gain_st.ToString("x") + "400020";
mem.write_word_segment_addr(10, int.Parse(final_reg, NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

Comment: `serial.write` which was my method in python, I have already re-written a method in C# called `write_word_segment_addr`. I need to add a `0x` in front of final_reg

Comment: Why do you need to add `0x`? `0xa` and `10` are totally the same integer.

Answer (score 0):

In case of **C#** you can use *string interpolation*:

```
 // 0x is not required for further conversion and can be dropped
 string final_reg = $"0x{gain_st:x}{400020}";
```

If you want to convert `final_reg` to integer, use `Convert`:

```
 write_word_segment_addr(Convert.Int32("A", 16), Convert.Int32(final_reg, 16));
```