# How to change Int array value in Unity which uses SPUP to be Hexadecimal value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, integer, serial-port, hex

I am making a hand grip strength program using Unity and combining it with a hand grip dynamometer device with a force capacity of 500N for my medical research. I used the Unity Pro (SPUP) serial port to connect to the device I was using, the device was successfully connected but the value displayed in Unity was in Int form, while the value displayed by the handheld dynamometer was in hexadecimal form.

To be frank I'm still new in the terms of coding and making a program and neither I have IT background, but my teacher force me to make a program so I just using SPUP (Serial port unity pro) to help me connecting the device I used with Unity. I have tried to find some tutorial of how to modify the C# script to convert Int value in Unity to be Hexadecimal value, but there's no information or YouTube tutorial of how to convert Int value to be hex value if the Unity has SPUP in it. How do I change the Int value in Unity which uses SPUP so that it can be hexadecimal value too? or how can I calibrate the Int number produced by Unity into ordinary decimal, so that the maximum value in the Unity program that I created can be the same as the maximum value of the device I am using (500N)? I hope someone in here can help me to debug the C# script so that I can make this Int value of Unity with SPUP to be able to converted in Hexadecimal value.

[image]

Comment: I am confused what exactly you are asking .. as I understand you either want the hexadecimal form of an integer value (=> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/convert-integer-to-hexadecimal-and-back-again)? Or maybe the hexadecimal you see on your device is actually just the hexadecimal form of the underlying 4 bytes of that integer value?